# How to build models in fatfree framework

Tags: model-view-controller, fat-free-framework

This might be a silly question, but I am trying to build a MVC structure on top of the fatfree framework, and I am wondering what is the best way to build the `Model` portion in the MVC. By `Model` I want it to mainly handle my interaction with the database. So should I just extend the sql mapper? I want the flexibility to swap out db or db engines further down the line without much change in the individual models, and also I want the models to be able to handle multiple tables with joins and not just a single table. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

> So should I just extend the sql mapper?

yes, this is a common way to do. You can find an example right here: 
http://fatfreeframework.com/sql-mapper#instantiation

> I want the models to be able to handle multiple tables with joins and not just a single table

Well, the easiest way is to extend your new model class with own methods, which loads the data from your other tables. You can find an explanation and sample here:

https://fatfreeframework.com/databases#SometimesItJustAin'tEnough

If that doesn't suit well, consider to create a VIEW in your database engine, that joins the tables right away and already returns the full data to the framework. For this purpose, read:

https://fatfreeframework.com/databases#ProsandCons

And if that still isn't enough, or your task can't be handled with a VIEW, you can have a look at this [bigger hammer](https://github.com/ikkez/f3-cortex), an additional ORM plugin I made, which has some relational features.

Comment: Bigger hammer indeed.